# Disable enter from firing from search charm to application

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am working on an application which has a search page that is both the default screen and the landing page when a query through the search charm is activated with my app open.  The layout is very similar to the Bing application, I have a textbox with a button to initiate search.  I have this button listening for an Enter Key Press, which works, but when the page is activated via the search charm, the Enter Key Press behavior is fired to my button when Enter is pressed in the search charm textbox causing search to fire twice.  The Bing application handles this behavior without double-searching so it can likely be done.  I was unable to figure a way to handle this, even making sure that the focus was on my button did not work as the Key Listener appear to listen for all keys pressed anywhere, including the search charm.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't simply make the button the default button? There shouldn't be a need to listen for key press events.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, how do I specify the button to be default?

Answer (score 0):

Just define the search button as the default one:

```
<Button IsDefault="true" ...>...</Button>
```

Like this, there is no need at all for key press events.

Comment: Unfortunately this property in not available in Metro => http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2875445-implement-iscancel-and-isdefault-properties-on-win

Comment: @PaulDeCarlo: What an oversight!